# How many times is DOSTUFF() called?

Tags: c#

```
try
{    
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
     {
       DoStuff();
       if (i>3 && 1== i% 2)
       {
         throw new Exception();
       }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  DoOtherStuff();
}
```

Comment: why don't you just run that to find out?

Comment: `DOSTUFF()` is never called. It isn't even defined. Also, what is `if (i>3 && 1== i% 2)`? Do you mean `((i>3) && (1==i%2))`?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Just think a bit to realize when the if is true and remember that the loop will stop executing when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Possibly belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

`DOSTUFF()` is called 0 times because C# method names are case-sensitive.

If you really meant `DoStuff()`, then assuming it is not an unimplemented [partial method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) and the method itself is not marked with a [conditional attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) specifying an undefined symbol, then it will be called 6 times as in [@MikeCito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849862/how-many-times-is-dostuff-called/5849908#5849908).

Comment: I wonder if the did that on purpose, or just typo.

Comment: @Mikecito - you're probably right, I've clarified.

Answer (score 1):

6 times.  When i hits 5 the remainder will be 1 and it will be greater than 3.